# Initializing the APIs Explorer

Tags: api, google-admin-sdk

I am an IT also G suite Administrator.

When I use API explorer :　https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update

I got this error :
Error initializing the APIs Explorer
Cannot find specified method in converted discovery doc.

I check this page : https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis
But I still don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

#### This seems to be a bug:

`Try this API` functionality is currently not working for some of the methods of [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk), including the ones from [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory) and [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started).

Instead of displaying the usual `Try this API` sidebar:

[image]

The message you mentioned is getting displayed:

[image]

Because of this, you cannot currently try these methods in the reference docs.

#### Issue Tracker:

This problem has already been reported before in Issue Tracker, and it has been forwarded internally by Google:

- [Error initializing the APIs Explorer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174070162)

Anyone affected by this, please consider clicking the star on the top-left of the referenced issue in order to receive updates and to help prioritizing this.